# Why is accessor of member array more than 300 time slower than array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using php 5.6 and I need a class to access an item at a certain position.
After some profiling I found that simply getting data was dreadfully slow...

Using the following sample code...

```
class A{
  protected $_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  public function at($pos){
    if( $pos < 0 || $pos > count($this->_x )){
      throw new Exception("out of range!");
    }
    return $this->_x[$pos];
  }
}

$time_pre = microtime(true);
$a = new A();
for( $j = 0; $j < 1000; ++$j )
{
  for( $i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i ){
    $x = $a->at($i);
  }
}
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Class={$exec_time}ms<br>";

$time_pre = microtime(true);
$a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for( $j = 0; $j < 1000; ++$j )
{
  for( $i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i ){
    $x = $a[$i];
  }
}

$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Array={$exec_time}ms<br>";
```

The output I got was

```
Class=0.51763796806335ms
Array=0.0022461414337158ms
```

Note that
- The class A() is created once only, I am just calling the function 'at()'
- The array is also only created once, I am just accessing it.
- **If I remove the 'if( $pos < 0 | ...' check, the code is still over 200 times slower.**

So my question is, why is the class so much slower than direct access to the function, effectively the at( ... ) function is just getting the value from the array.

Comment: The method is *not* equivalent to the direct access at all. Besides the actual method call, there's at least an `if` and, worse, a `count()` in it. The latter may account for the major part of the difference.

Comment: @HannoBinder, thanks, but, as I said in my post, if I remove the if statement, the code is still 200 times slower.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. However, array memory access is among the fastest ways to access data in RAM. Every method call involves an overhead. If that alone would justify a 200x penalty I'm not sure though.

Comment: @HannoBinder count() goes in constant time complexity O(1) in fact

Comment: @HannoBinder furthermore, in both cases, I am getting a value from an array, so the 200x slowdown cannot really be explained by access in RAM, (whatever that really means in this case).

Comment: What I mean is: "Pure" array access is almost as fast as `$var = $var2;`. On the other hand, `$a->at($i)` means an access to `$a`, then to it's VMT, then setting up parameter(s), then doing the method call, *then* comes the fast, simple array access, and finally the method returns passing its result back. - Thinking about it, even in pure assembler, the difference would probably be in the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Looking at it some more, I say that any decent (JIT-) compiler would eliminate the second loop completely because it can statically prove that `$x` is never read (i.e. its assignment is redundant) and that reading `$a[$i]` does not have any side effect. A (virtual) method call is much harder to eliminate, because you generally cannot know at compile time the actual method to be called at runtime. Try something like `$x = $x + $a[$i];` and output the value of `$x` at the end. This should pretty much make sure the loop is not optimized away.

Comment: Sorry @HannoBinder, but that does not explain a 200x slow down, I understand some kind of slow down, of course, but not 200x.
Your statement about code been removed or not, is not true, any compiler could/would remove the code, but not php, (well not php 5.6 as far as I am aware).
Finally, I am not sure what statistics have to do with it, sorry, I just don't understand your comment.